# Can we set weighted policy on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services

Can we set weighted policy on s3, if yes. What is the step by step process.
I tried that and have a problem that traffic is routed to one endpoint only.
I done research on that and found might it is a problem with CNAME mentioned in cloudfront.
Please suggest correct values also for that.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

S3 objects are only stored in a single region, meaning that in order to access that particular object, you must go through that regions API Endpoint.

For example, if you had "image.jpg" stored in a bucket "s3-images", that was created in the eu-west-1 region - in order to download that file you must go through the appropiate S3 Endpoint for the eu-west-1 Region:

```
s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

If you tried to use another Endpoint, you will get an error, pointing out that you are using the wrong endpoint

If your question is relating to using CloudFront in front of S3, you need to set your DNS CNAME to resolve to your CloudFront Distributions CNAME in order for your users to be routed through CloudFront, rather than hitting S3 directly:

```
[cdn.example.com] -CNAME-> [d12345.cloudfront.net] -> s3://some-bucket
```

Comment: Hi,
It is really helpful to me and it is working.
Now I had applied weighted policy on Route53 in a 50:50 ratio.
Now when I am hitting the website continuously multiple times, every time it is fetching the data from bucket A.
However I had invalidated the cache in cloudfront for bucket A.